# VS2015 MSVCP140D.dll not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

В какой-то момент перестал запускаться Debug в студии с сообщением:

> Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует
>   MSVCP140D.dll. Попробуйте переустановить программу.

Если добавить путь `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT` в `Debugging` - `Environment` - `PATH`, то запускается нормально. Раньше этого не требовалось. Что могло поломаться?

**UPD**

Пробовал создать новый пустой консольный проект, та же ситуация.

**UPD**

`Debug` вариант со статическим рантаймом (как предложил в комментариях Duracell) ожидаемо запускается нормально. А вот `Release` работает как со статически слинкованым рантаймом так и с dll.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю твою проблему - то исправляется так - настройки проэкта->с\с++->создание кода->библиотека времени выполнения==многопоточная mt\d

Comment: @Duracell, да, в таком варианте запускается, но это скорее не исправление, а сокрытие проблемы, т.к. все таки хотелось бы иметь runtime не слинкованый с exe.

Comment: У инсталлятора 2015 студии вроде был режим «починить инсталляцию».

Comment: А перестало запускаться только на одном проекте, или на новом, чистом проекте тоже? (И да, есть ли файл  MSVCP140D.dll на вашем компьютере?)

Comment: @VladD, на чистом проекте то же самое, файл `MSVCP140D.dll` лежит по адресу `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT`

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: А когда строите Release, файл MSVCP140.dll (без D!) оказывается в каталоге с программой?

Comment: @VladD, "починить инсталляцию" как тяжелую артиллерию хотелось бы оставить на крайний случай. Все таки интересно что могло такого произойти.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian - ок, помню, когда-то давно тоже имел подобную проблему - решил я ее так - кинул в системную папку требуемые библиотеки - я не помню точно какая папка - пойму syswow64, могу ошибаться

Comment: Например, какая-то программа при дезинсталляции по глупости снесла debug redistributable VC. Или ещё что-нибудь такое.

Comment: @VladD, MSVCP140.dll в релизе не копируется в каталог с программой.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Ага! А откуда он грузится? Можете посмотреть, когда вы запускаете программу (Release) через отладчик, в списке модулей точный путь?

Comment: `msvcp140.dll` грузится  из `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Хм. А ну-ка подождите, гляну, откуда грузится MSVCP140D.dll на моей системе.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: `Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'.` То есть таки грузит из SysWOW64. Посмотрите, есть ли он у вас там.

Comment: У меня в `SysWOW64` только `msvcp140.dll`, видимо в этом проблема.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Ага. Кто-то снёс его. Я бы подозревал чей-нибудь глючный деинсталлятор. Ну так скопируйте его туда. Или можно переустановить debug redistributable.

Comment: Всем спасибо, восстановил через инсталлятор установку (чтобы не гадать, какие ещё файлы пропали), полет нормальный.

Comment: Окей, тогда оформлю диалог в комментариях как ответ. Вы использовали инсталлятор redist или восстановление установки студии?

Comment: @VladD студийный родной инсталлятор, у него есть опция repair

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Суммируя расследование и диалог в комментариях:

Библиотека `msvcp140d.dll` является частью Visual C++, это [отладочная версия рантайм-библиотеки С++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features) и ставится при установке Visual Studio на ваш компьютер. Обычно она находятся в `%WINDIR%\System32` для 32-битных систем и в `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64` для 64-битных систем (для 32-битных программ). Поскольку это более-менее общедоступное место, библиотеку может по недосмотру удалить какое-нибудь другое приложение, что судя по всему и произошло.

Версия библиотеки находится в `<каталог Visual Studio>\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT`, и его можно скопировать оттуда. Но лучшим решением является воспользоваться опцией `repair` инсталлятора Visual Studio, который доставит исчезнувшие файлы.

---

Заметьте, что отладочная версия библиотеки `msvcp140d.dll` (в отличие от релизной `msvcp140.dll`) не является частью redistributable. Поэтому если вы хотите разворачивать на машине клиента компоненты, требующие отладочную версию рантайма, лучше всего либо статически скомпоноваться, либо таскать с собой в каталоге инсталляции копию файлов из `Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT`.

Дополнительная информация на MSDN: [Preparing a Test Machine To Run a Debug Executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/preparing-a-test-machine-to-run-a-debug-executable).

Comment: Последния ссылка умерла.

Comment: @Penggrin Оживил